# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}

Tags: java, android, xml

Main activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Add a Note"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText item;
    Button add;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        item = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        add = findViewById(R.id.button);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        itemList = FileHelper.readData(this);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,itemList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String itemName = item.getText().toString();
                itemList.add(itemName);
                item.setText("");
                FileHelper.writeData(itemList,getApplicationContext());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

FileHelper.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileHelper {
    public static final String FILENAME = "listinfo.dat";

    public static void writeData(ArrayList<String> item, Context context)
    {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oas = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oas.writeObject(item);
            oas.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public  static  ArrayList<String> readData(Context context){
        ArrayList<String> itemList = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            try {
                itemList = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return itemList;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error and the app crashes before it starts
I get the following error message:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7111
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)

Comment: `readData()` probably is returning `null`. *Always* log your exceptions, so you can learn from Logcat if any of those `catch` blocks is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

**ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);**

is returning null. this is not caught in try/catch  as well so its crashing